# How to skip an if controller on JMeter if previous sample's response is changed to OK after failure?

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter

I am running a JMeter beanshell sampler test, after which I have an if controller that should run if the last JMeter sample is ok.

I have this working, however, I have to ensure if the first test fails, it needs to be changed to a pass but does not continue to the if controller.

I have tried ticking the ignore status checkbox in the Response Assertion of the test and adding a BeanShell PostProcessor that changes the previous test response to OK. These are not options as it results in continuing to the if controller.

So:
- if test passes continue to if controller - completed
- if test fails, change to pass but skip if controller

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to design your test as follows:

1. Add [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) config element and configure it as below:

   - Start: `1`
   - Increment: `1`
   - Reference Name: `N`
2. Add a Beanshell PostProcessor as a child of the first test and put the next code into it's "Script" area

   ```
   int test = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("N"));

   if (test == 1 && !prev.isSuccessful()) {
       prev.setSuccessful(true);
   }
   ```
3. Add If Controller after the first test and use the following condition:

   ```
   ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} && "${N}" != 1
   ```

So

- Counter will hold current test number and store it into JMeter Variable `N`
- Beanshell PostProcessor will mark your test as successful if it is "first" and "failed"
- If Controller will execute nested samplers if following conditions are met:

  - Previous test is successful
  - Previous test is not "first"

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more information on proper conditional execution of JMeter samplers.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define a separate variable which controls the if controller or change the variable from fail to pass after the if controller's condition has been evaluated.